# fadeToggle is malfunctioning with animate width?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my attempt at replicating the code I have. For some reason, the code works perfectly in jsfiddle, but malfunctions with my own website. Maybe someone can somehow figure out what the issue is regardless.

http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/g0teoyrc/

So like I said, it works well in jsfiddle, but in my actual website, clicking the Button makes Div2 instantly disappear and then instantly reappear again before beginning its fade animation. Obviously this looks very bad and weird.

Does anyone have ideas as to what might be happening?

HTML

```
<body>
    <section id="wrapper">
        <div id="button">B</div>
        <div id="Div1">Div1</div>
        <div id="Div2">Div2</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#Div1{
    height:400px;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}

#Div2{
    height:400px;
    width:380px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20;
    background:green;
    display:none;
    margin-left:380px; 
}

#button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function() {


    $('#Div2').fadeToggle(300);

    var toggleWidth = $("#Div1").width() == 380 ? "1000px" : "380px"; 
    $('#Div1').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300); 


});
```

Comment: do you have any other jQuery/javascript code attached to this element (#button or #div2) - by event handlers for example?

Comment: Include document().ready function that will solve your problem

Comment: also check if you don't have global effects settings - jQuery.fx.interval and jQuery.fx.off wrongly setup somewhere - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fx.off/

Comment: @shershen No I don't. Also, i checked global effects settings per your suggestions and didn't find anything.

Comment: @RiteshK I tried wrapping the code in "$( document ).ready(function() {" and the problem persisted somehow. I will probably end up pasting my entire website code here haha, this is too weird of a problem!

Comment: then as a next step you could create a full copy of your website page and share the link on it. because all obvious mistakes were mentioned.

Comment: try using different version of jquery

Comment: Alright, can someone check out the fiddle here? http://jsfiddle.net/neowot/z1xxsu8t/1/ (Sorry for the ugly website) Click on the dropdown and choose "1". Then type something into the textbox and hit enter. You should see the "LeftPanel" div now. Now click on the circular skyblue button. Here is where the problem begins. The JS code in question is under the comment "Relevant Code Here".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Works for me as fiddle**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery animate </title>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<style>
#wrapper{
    width:1000px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
#Div1{
    height:400px;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:blue;
}

#Div2{
    height:400px;
    width:380px;
    position:absolute;
    top:20;
    background:green;
    display:none;
    margin-left:380px; 
}

#button{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background:orange;
    cursor:pointer;
}

</style>
<body> 

<section id="wrapper">
        <div id="button">B</div>
        <div id="Div1">Div1</div>
        <div id="Div2">Div2</div>
</section>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('#button').click(function() {


        $('#Div2').fadeToggle(300);

        var toggleWidth = $("#Div1").width() == 380 ? "1000px" : "380px"; 
        $('#Div1').animate( {'width': toggleWidth}, 300); 


    });   
  });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```